# centos 7 font problem unable to read words

Tags: centos

hello friends after last update (centos 7 3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64) i am unable to read text in terminal and also right click menu 
 looks like  below screenshot
[image]

why is this . How to fix  this ?

Comment: Looks like a wrong configured screen. But that should not happen for quite some time now... try configuring your screen for lower resolution. We will need details for your setup (graphics card, screen, exact version of the distribution, is everything up to date). The version you cite is presumably for some package that you updated, and blame for this mess. You could try to roll back, or check for updates.

Comment: thank you @vonbrand      : lspci     00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)   and  display resolution is set to 1024x768    please tell me if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

Had this kind of thing recently, we had to install a new PCIe graphics card to resolve it.

This was happening on a HP desktop with integrated graphics. we assume that CentOS now requires a little more grunt...

This happened when updating to the same kernel you mention. I doubt it's coincidence.

Comment: you are right , i have booted it with old kernel (    `3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64`    )   Now it looking fine